# VS "Cannot open source file" error, trying to build for the pi4 on a windows machine

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, remote-debugging, raspberry-pi4

I have the pi as the remote build machine, I have the files in the pi, I added them to include directories but it still says it can't open them. [Here's a picture showing how they are included but I'm still getting the errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHviL.png)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please embed images in your question to make it easier to read.

Comment: Is the path correct? Please provide some information about the directory.